# How to retrieve yahoo basic chart of currency using javascript and json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am quite new at javascript and web programming in general. I'm trying to make a basic chart of stock prices using the Google Visualization Chart API.I want to retrieve basic graph of currency rate using yahoo finance.

How do I read this finance data into a javascript object?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can get a list of data which return by a String .
for example:

```
data: "[stock1:{max:1,min:0,5,days:0.5}]";
```

I assume The callback method of request is

```
function callback (data){
 var data = eval(data)//or eval(data.data) please use the javascript console to see the structure of response data
// data will become the javascript object
}
```

Comment: yes it fine but, i want to retrieve yahoo live currency basic chart.I have retrieved live currency rate.How can i do this please help me.

Comment: There is a graph on this link "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=usdinr=x" i want this graph to be displayed in my application

Comment: first you need to find the interface (or service ) the yahoo provide to get the chart.